# Consulta Multiplicar Javascript y Restablecer

Tags: php, javascript

tengo una consulta.

Estoy haciendo una pequeño programa para registrar ventas, en esta labor me encuentro con una duda.

Tengo 3 Inputs

```
Input1 Cantidad
Input2 Precio
Input3 Total
```

Ahora con Javascript he logrado que al escribir los valores correspondientes se multiplique el precio por la cantidad Y de resultado en el total.

El problema está que cuando cambio el valor de cantidad, se sigue multiplicando por el resultado anterior.

¿Como hago para que al cambiar regrese a su valor anterior y vuelva a multiplicarse?

Comment: A que te refieres con se sigue multiplicando por el resultado anterior, si cambias cantidad o precio el nuevo valor debe calcularse basado en estos nuevos valores.

Comment: Podrías mostrar los avances que haz realizado relacionados al tema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function calcular(campo) {
  //Si se borra todo el texto debe ponerse algun valor inicial
  campo.value = !campo.value.length ? 0 : campo.value;

  //Obtengo la cantidad y el precio
  var cantidad = document.querySelector('#cantidad').value;
  var precio = document.querySelector('#precio').value;

  //Establezco el total basado en el calculo
  document.querySelector('#total').value = cantidad*precio;
}
```

```html
<label for="cantidad">Cantidad: </label>
<input type="number" id="cantidad" name="cantidad" onkeyup="calcular(this)" value="1"/><br/>

<label for="precio">Precio: </label>
<input type="number" id="precio" name="precio" onkeyup="calcular(this)" value="1"/><br/>

<label for="total">Total: </label>
<input type="number" id="total" name="total" readonly/><br/><br/>
```